# Database abstraction layer for Scala

Tags: java, sql, scala, database-abstraction

Hello i am searching for a database abstraction layer, which abstracts my SQL Statements/Queries so i can support multiple SQL dialects without having to worry about the right syntax.

I wonder if someone has experience with [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) or [SQL Builder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) and is it what i am looking for? I couldn't find any informations if it abstracts the SQL Statement/Query in the way i want to.

Comment: Have you seen Slick? http://slick.typesafe.com/  very powerful and kind of trendy right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://slick.typesafe.com
It supports a wide range of systems (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/introduction.html#supported-database-systems)